# How to mock a method using ts-mockito?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, ts-mockito

I want create a mocked object of a class via ts-mockito@2.5.0 but I am unable to set it up properly.

Here's contrived test case:

```
import {expect} from "chai";
import {
    mock,
    when,
} from "ts-mockito";

class MockMe {
    public doStuff(): string {
        return "I AM THE ORIGINAL VALUE";
    }
}

describe("ts-mockito weirdness", async () => {
    it("should create a mock with specific return values", async () => {
        const mocked = mock(MockMe);

        await when(mocked.doStuff()).thenReturn("I AM MOCKED");

        const actualReturnValue = mocked.doStuff();

        expect(actualReturnValue).to.eq("I AM MOCKED");
    });
});
```

As the test-case implies, I expect the return value of "I AM MOCKED" from my mock.

But I am getting a ts-mockito-specifc object instead, containing properties like: `methodStubCollection`, `matchers`,  `mocker`, and `name`.

[image: Screenshot of unexpected response from ts-mockito]

How am I supposed to setup the mock that it works as intended?

---

Sidenote: This test-case is only to showcase the weird behavior I am experiencing. It's not my actual test. I want to use a mock in a unit-test for a different service.)

Comment: I opened an issue asking for improved error message if possible: https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/issues/169

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the [`instance`](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/issues/87) call due to technical limitation of TypeScript.

```
import {
    instance,
    mock,
    when,
} from "ts-mockito";

const mockitoMock = mock(MockMe);
const actualInstanceOfMock = instance(mocked).doStuff();
actualInstanceOfMock.doStuff() // will return your mocked value
```

Comment: I use Typescript infrequently. When I come back to it, this is one of those errors where I think "oh god, this looks familiar, and I remember it was both bone-headed and hard to figure out." It happens just rarely enough that I forget the fix.