# Issues mocking objects in Typescript with ts-mockito

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, ts-mockito

When I try to use `mockito-ts` to mock the return value of member functions on instances of mocked objects, I get that the member function is not a function.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'methodStubCollection')`

When I ran this in the larger project I am working on, I had a different message indicating a similar issue. Basically, `mockObject.mockMethod is not a function`.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031876/how-to-mock-a-method-using-ts-mockito) and others emphasize that the `instance` call is critical, and I think I've done that right. But I still see issues.

Here is the minimal reproducible code example:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dwf_backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Server for DrawWithFriends app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/server.js\"",
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "TJ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

test/mockito_test.test.ts:

```
import { mock, instance, anything, when } from 'ts-mockito'


class B {
    public doTheThing(str: string): number {
        return str.length;
    }
}

class A {
    private readonly b: B;
    constructor(b: B) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public doTheMainThing() {
        this.b.doTheThing('strrr');
    }
}

describe('test cases', () => {
    it('passes', () => {
    });

    it('mocks', () => {
        const mockedB: B = mock(B);

        const a = new A(instance(mockedB));
        a.doTheMainThing();
    });

    it('controls the mocked method', () => {
        const mockedB: B = mock(B);

        const instanceB: B = instance(mockedB);
        console.log(`instanceB is: ${JSON.stringify(instanceB)}`);

        when(instanceB.doTheThing(anything())).thenReturn(4);

        const a = new A(instanceB);
        a.doTheMainThing();
    });
});
```

run with `npm run test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Stubbing method calls](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito#stubbing-method-calls) doc, we should pass the mocked object returned by the `mock` function rather than the instance object returned by the `instance` function to the `when` function to stub method and its return value.

It should be:

```
const mockedB: B = mock(B);
const instanceB: B = instance(mockedB);
when(mockedB.doTheThing(anything())).thenReturn(4);
```

**NOT**

```
const mockedB: B = mock(B);
const instanceB: B = instance(mockedB);
when(instanceB.doTheThing(anything())).thenReturn(4);
```

An working example:

```
import { mock, instance, anything, when } from 'ts-mockito'

class B {
  public doTheThing(str: string): number {
    return str.length;
  }
}

class A {
  private readonly b: B;
  constructor(b: B) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public doTheMainThing() {
    return this.b.doTheThing('strrr');
  }
}

describe('test cases', () => {
  it('controls the mocked method', () => {
    const mockedB: B = mock(B);
    const instanceB: B = instance(mockedB);
    when(mockedB.doTheThing(anything())).thenReturn(4);

    const a = new A(instanceB);
    const actual = a.doTheMainThing();
    expect(actual).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76133872/index.test.ts
  test cases
    ✓ controls the mocked method (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.665 s, estimated 1 s
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for pointing that out! 

Another thing I had to sort out in my actual implementation was that I was using abstract class, and I had to actually mock the class itself.